# Remove HTTP Header Info

Tags: c, http, sockets, header

In C is there a way to exclude the HTTP header information that comes with the data when using `recv()` on a socket? I am trying to read some binary data and all I want is the actual binary information, not the HTTP header information. The current data received looks like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 3314
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Last-Modified: Tue, 20 Mar 2012 14:51:34 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "45da99f1a86cd1:6b9"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 20 Aug 2012 14:10:08 GMT
Connection: close 

╪ α
```

I would like only to read the binary portion of the file. (That's obviously not all the binary, only that much was displayed since I printed the output from my recv loop as a string and the first NULL char is after that small binary string).

I just need to get rid of the header portion, is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: I don't think there is, I know that in C++ there is though. There might be some libraries out there to help in C. But don't you need to know the Content-Length property so that you can allocate enough space for your payload?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you need to extract the value of the `Content-Length` to know the size of the binary data to be read otherwise it will be impossible to know whether all data has been received. A simple approach to consume, and mostly ignore, the header portion is to read the incoming data byte-by-byte until `"\r\n\r\n"` is encountered, which indicates the end of the header section and the beginning of the content.

Answer (score 9):

You would be better of using some HTTP parsing library like [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/)

If you want to do it yourself:

You can search for `'\r\n\r\n'` (two `\r\n`) which separates HTTP headers and contents, and use string/buffer after that.

Also, you need to get `Content-Length` from header and read that many bytes as http content.

Something like:

```
/* http_resp has data read from recv */
httpbody = strstr(http_resp, "\r\n\r\n");
if(httpbody) 
    httpbody += 4; /* move ahead 4 chars
/* now httpbody  has just data, stripped down http headers */
```

Note: make sure `strstr` does not overrun the memory, may be using `strnstr` (not sure this exists or not) or similar functions.