# C++ Send data to PHP and handle Response

Tags: c++

```
void SendHardverInfo(){
    DWORD VolumeSerialNumber;

if (GetVolumeInformation("C:\\", 0, 0, &VolumeSerialNumber, 0, 0, 0, 0) == 0)
{
    return;
}

UUID uuid;

UuidCreateSequential(&uuid);

SYSTEM_INFO SystemInfo;

GetSystemInfo(&SystemInfo);

DWORD ComputerHardwareId1 = VolumeSerialNumber ^ 0x12B586FE;

DWORD ComputerHardwareId2 = *(DWORD*)(&uuid.Data4[2]) ^ 0x5D78A569;

DWORD ComputerHardwareId3 = ((*(WORD*)(&uuid.Data4[6]) & 0xFFFF) | (SystemInfo.wProcessorArchitecture << 16)) ^ 0xF45BC123;

DWORD ComputerHardwareId4 = ((SystemInfo.wProcessorLevel & 0xFFFF) | (SystemInfo.wProcessorRevision << 16)) ^ 0xB542D8E1;



//SENDSERVER
WSADATA wsaData;
if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData) != 0) {
    return;
}
SOCKET Socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
struct hostent *host;
host = gethostbyname("www.mysite.com");
SOCKADDR_IN SockAddr;
SockAddr.sin_port = htons(80);
SockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
SockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = *((unsigned long*)host->h_addr);
if (connect(Socket, (SOCKADDR*)(&SockAddr), sizeof(SockAddr)) != 0){

    return;
}


char Text[256];
ZeroMemory(Text, sizeof(Text));
sprintf(Text, "%08X-%08X-%08X-%08X", ComputerHardwareId1, ComputerHardwareId2, ComputerHardwareId3, ComputerHardwareId4);

char link[500];
strcat(link, "GET /api/hardverinfo.php?hardverinfo=");
strcat(link, Text);
strcat(link, " HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.mysite.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n");

send(Socket, link, strlen(link), 0);

char buffer[10000];
int nDataLength;
while ((nDataLength = recv(Socket, buffer, 10000, 0)) > 0){
    int i = 0;
    while (buffer[i] >= 32 || buffer[i] == '\n' || buffer[i] == '\r') {
        i += 1;
    }
}

closesocket(Socket);
WSACleanup();

printf(link);
return;
//ENDSEND
}
```

Hi I have this code, its working and good. But After I send the GET request to the website, than I wanted to handle the answer, so for example after the get is done website give back OK and I want to handle this OK in my application, how can i do that?

Comment: Why don't you start by showing us what you have done so far?

Answer (score 1):

Change your GET request header to this

```
" HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.mysite.com\r\nContent-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n\r\n";
```

instead of your header part at the end. That should force your php server to response in a format readable to your application.

Comment: HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Date: Wed, 06 Jul 2016 18:58:06 GMT

Content-Type: text/html

Content-Length: 0

Connection: close

Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d6196ca171eec28bbcc68a393b698107b1467831486; expires=Thu, 06-Jul-17 18:58:06 GMT; path=/; domain=.mysite.com; HttpOnly

Server: cloudflare-nginx

CF-RAY: 2be549487a812be2-AMS

I got back this, not the PHP file echo value, why is it?

Comment: if I put the buffer to write the recv into a text file I got the upper, if I put the recv into the fprint, i got this: ‹˙U‹ěěS3Ű=HpÉu).ÇuV…

Comment: try to erase all headers like i did. Then what is left is your server response.

Comment: `char buf[256];

 memset(buf, NULL, 256);


 recv(Socket, buf, 255, NULL);
 std::string result = buf;

 result.erase(0, result.find_last_of("\r\n\r\n") + 1);
 if (buffer != NULL){
  FILE* file;

  if (fopen_s(&file, "ASD.txt", "w") != 0)
  {
   return;
  }

  fprintf(file, "%s", result);

  fclose(file);`
If I do it like this, in the TXT I get (NULL)

Comment: for %s your should put result.c_str(), correct it and check

Comment: Its underlined. in the PHP file I have an echo 'OK'; thats why I dont understand this. Why I didnt get the right text back.

Comment: `char buf[256];
memset(buf, NULL, 256);
recv(Socket, buf, 255, NULL);
std::string result = buf;

//result.erase(0, result.find_last_of("\r\n\r\n") + 1);
result.c_str();
if (buffer != NULL){
 FILE* file;

  if (fopen_s(&file, "ASD.txt", "w") != 0)
  {
   return;
  }

  fprintf(file, "%s", result);

  fclose(file);
 }
 closesocket(Socket);
 WSACleanup();

 printf(link);
 return;`

Comment: well i think that you should try changing the request by adding this to it: `" HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.mysite.com\r\nContent-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n\r\n";` instead of your header part at the end.

Comment: If I put the buffer into the fprintf I got this: http://pastebin.com/7D4B4sZZ I changed the OK to DONE to see its in it or not. But now How can I remove the another text?:D

Comment: Just put it into string and make `.erase(0,result.find_last_of("\r\n\r\n")+1);`.
Also mark my answer as correct if your problem is solved.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116630/discussion-between-dualcore-and-vbnetguy).

Comment: `std::string result = buffer;
result.erase(0, result.find_last_of("\r\n\r\n") + 1);`
If I put the things like this than in the fprint I use result variable the ASD.txt is empty, If I put the buffer into the fprint i see the same like before what you can see on pastebin.

Comment: Your question is now answered. You're left with a trivial task that should not be solved here. According to your problem you can refer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12039366/remove-http-header-info

Comment: Okey, thanks for your help. But I still dont understand how will I cut down the HTTP header things to get back just the usefull data.